# tmux message-command-style not having an effect

Tags: terminal, tmux

I am in the process of customising tmux to my tastes. From `man tmux` I have read about the following style attributes for the statusline:

- `bright` (or `bold`)
- `dim`
- `underscore`
- `blink`
- `reverse`
- `hidden`
- `italics`

With the exception of `underscore` (which underlines the text), none of these have any effect except changing the colours (if anything). The manual does not as far as I can see specify what each attribute is supposed to do. Can anyone tell me what they are each supposed to do so I can check if they work or not.

For example, I assume `italics` should make the text italic. If this is not happening, is this likely to be a misconfiguration of my terminal?

Note: my terminal does support italics. I do see italic text in Vim for example.

Answer (score 1):

Not all terminals support italics, and not all terminal descriptions support the italic feature.  They are only possibilities, not universally available.

Comment: The strange this is that my terminal does support italic text.